# asp.net ajax photo gallery tutorial

Tags: asp.net, ajax, photo-gallery

Is there any tutorial on how to make a simple asp.net ajax photo gallery without comments and other stuff. I'm looking for something really simple - a grid of clickable images and a popup window with the chosen image.

Answer (score 0):

[Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) is very popular, you can control the render of your `<a/>` tags from the the server side or add them dynamically to your DOM with jQuery AJAX calls:

Comment: you didn't get the question - I was asking for the tutorial on how to build photo gallery by myself